# Select2 Bootstrap AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Alguém utiliza o Select2 Bootstrap no AngularJS? Estou com um problema... quando clico na lista suspensa (options) exibe o valor correto que vem do banco, mas na exibição aparece sempre o primeiro registro. Quando tiro o select2 funciona normal.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor coloque algum do código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente como está seu código, mas eu uso dessa forma:

```
<select chosen="chosen.options" id="especialidade" ng-model="specialty" no-results-text="chosen.empty" class="form-control">
      <option selected ng-click="search(true, false)">{{chosen.specialty}}</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in specialties" value="{{item.name}}" ng-click="search(true, false)">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Esse primeiro option eu coloco o selected e minha interpolação é um texto de "Selecione" padrão.
Já o segundo option é onde vou percorrer minhas opções de especialidade.

No meu caso, ao clicar em uma das especialidades eu tenho um ng-click que faz uma ação, se quiser só listar não precisa usar o ng-click.